# can android studio run in 4GB Ram with external android phone?

Tags: android, ubuntu

The RAM of my PC is 4GB. I am using ubuntu 16.04. I am having trouble while running Android studio. My PC is hanged even if I am using my phone for running the APK. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some things you can do:

- Use the [latest version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html) of Android Studio
- User Power Save Mode: Go to File -> Power Save Mode
- Reduce the memory being used by Android Studio: Help -> Edit Custom VM Options, then enter this:

  `studio.vmoptions
  -Xmx512m`
- Use the latest version of the Gradle Plugin: When creating a new project from Android Studio, it is the default selected version
- User Power Save Mode: Go to File -> Power Save Mode
- Enable Offline Work: Android Studio Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Check Offline work

Please notice, some features may be disabled.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TENdS9Qqcc

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thats my setup.

But I see Windows10 freezing often.

The issue is usually while gradle building.

The last version of Android Studio (3.0 released yesterday) state that it did improvements.